# addEventListener not going inside else

Tags: javascript

I'm expecting two behaviors:

a) a new div box ("box4") to be inserted on my HTML when clicking on a div box ("boton") that i already have on the html file.

b) them on a new click on the "boton", make the "box 4" dissapear again.

the first stage its working, the box2 appears, but nothing happens on the next click

this his my js code:

```
let boton = document.querySelector("#btn");
insertaraqui = document.querySelector(".container");
let btnstate = "hidden";

console.log(btnstate)

boton.addEventListener( "click", () => {

   if( btnstate == "hidden" ) {

       let boxnuevo = `<div class="box"id="box4">4</div>`
       insertaraqui.innerHTML += boxnuevo ;
       btnstate = "show"
       console.log(btnstate)

   } else {

       alert("hola")
       let box4 = document.querySelector("#box4");
       box4.remove()
       console.log(btnstate)

   }
})
```

Comment: Pay very careful attention to your syntax. `<div class="box"id="box4">4</div>` -> `<div class="box" id="box4">4</div>` with a space between attributes to avoid potential parsing errors.

Comment: ty for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue in your code was that you didn't set `btnstate` to hidden after the second click, that was giving an error because your click will go the `else` block and there is no `#box4` to remove, here is a work snippet:

```js
let boton = document.querySelector("#btn");
let insertaraqui = document.querySelector(".container");
let btnstate = "hidden";
console.log(btnstate);

boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (btnstate == "hidden") {
    let boxnuevo = `<div class="box"id="box4">4</div>`;
    insertaraqui.innerHTML += boxnuevo;
    btnstate = "show";
    console.log(btnstate);
  } else {
    let box4 = document.querySelector("#box4");
    btnstate = "hidden";
    box4.remove();
    console.log(btnstate);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<button id='btn'>add</button>
```

Comment: ty for the answer! in the procces i notice i was having also another trouble, the new box was being inserted into an existing div, and then i couldnt remover from there. i had to inserte the nex box outside any other div. a friend explain to me that you cannot remove "part" of a div

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `btnstate` to `hidden` when you remove the box.

Answer (score 0):

you can just hide or show an already inserted html element, and it will be better because you are not modified the DOM, you just toggle a class.

```js
const hideElementButton = document.getElementById("button-insert-div");
const deleteElementButton = document.getElementById("button-delete-element");
const boxFourElement = document.getElementById("box-four");
const boxContainerElement = document.getElementById("box-container");

// with toggle you will add or remove a class, and in this case, the class is just to hide the element
hideElementButton.addEventListener("click", () => boxFourElement.classList.toggle("hide-element"))

deleteElementButton.addEventListener("click", () => boxContainerElement.innerText = "")
```

```css
.hide-element {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="box-container">
    <div class="box" id="box-four">4</div>
  </div>
  <button id="button-insert-div">show or hide box</button>
  <button id="button-delete-element">delete element</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ty! this seems like a cleaner way to do it!  but the html content inside that element doents dissapear, just the styling. should i embeed the html inside the css to  make it dissapear too?

Comment: The idea is that you don't delete the element on the DOM, you just hide it, if you need to delete it, you can do something like, boxContainer.innerText = "" , I modified the response this that option